# A user program or a kernel module?

Tags: linux, events, module, linux-device-driver

One sbc running Linux. I am running project that this board is dedicated to the robot brain. I plan to make a daemon process listening for button event. When the button is pressed, a user program will be triggered. And that program will load some driver such a motor driver, sensors ... Or that triggered program better be a module itself? Are there better way than this? Please provide your argument.

Comment: Can you *please* stop re-posting the same question over and over again?

Answer (score 0):

I would go for user space if you don't have a good reason to do it in kernel. SBC probably already have buttons exported as GPIO class devices, so detecting changes with poll will be dead simple.